# Is the charge density of a polarised object, 0 or negative?

Tags: electrostatics, charge

if I place a negative point charge above a metal plate so that the metal plate polarizes completely with all the electrons on the bottom and a bunch of ions on top, would the charge density on the top plate =
a) 0
b) - the charge on the bottom plate

because both kind of make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider only the top half of the plate, the charge density would be positive. If you consider the bottom half, the charge density would be negative. If you consider the entire volume of plate, the average charge density would be zero as the plate on a whole is still electrically neutral .

Answer (score 0):

In the ideal (and not quite correct) model in which the capacitor's charge resides only on the infinitesimally thin surface, the charge density *on the surface* would be infinite.  Actually, the charge is distributed in a thin but finite layer on the surfaces of the plates.